# Invalid Token message on Login

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

While logging in the jomsocial or joomla administration page, an "invalid tokken" error is shown first ... then after two three page refreshes it gets cleared. Have once installe a custom plugin and later uninstalled it.. After that these problem arrived.....

Should there be any change in configuration file configuration.php

```
class JConfig {
public $offline = '0';
  //other lines regards to the site details hence not pasted..
   public $MetaTitle = '0';
public $MetaAuthor = '0';
public $sef = '1';
public $sef_rewrite = '1';
public $sef_suffix = '1';
public $unicodeslugs = '0';
public $feed_limit = '10';

    public $lifetime = '15';
public $session_handler = 'database';
public $MetaRights = '';
public $sitename_pagetitles = '0';
public $force_ssl = '0';
public $feed_email = 'site';
public $cookie_domain = '';
public $cookie_path = '';
```

or is it regarded to some modification in default.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "System - Cache" plugin is often responsible for this issue, as the login form attempts to create a unique token on each page, and that plugin takes a snapshot of a page after it has been processed, and will deliver it unmodified to the end user. If that plugin is enabled, disable it.

Also, if you are getting these issues in the Joomla backend, it is possible that you are using an Apache cache module. Ask your system administrator to disable mod_cache if it's enabled.

Comment: The system-cache plugin is disabled... there are plugins like system-redirect, system-cache-cleaner, system-log which are which are enabled.... I think all these are needed.... isin't it

Comment: oh wait wait ..... I got the solution.... thanks a lot Matt beckman, I have now noticed som of the plugins of alphauserpoints still shown enabled after uninstallation... By disabling all that plugins... its now working... Thanks a lot Matt , ur reply helped me to peep into that plugin manager..

Comment: The plugin (`plugins/system/cache.php`) actually contains code to cater for the token (in joomla 1.5.23 it should be ~ line 82). It's quite 'brute-force', so might be subject to some bugs, but the intention is at least there.

Answer (score 0):

Well,Its probably because of cache created by module. Try clearing all the cookies and cache of the browser and try again. If problem perist try disabling the cache of the newly installed module/plugin.Its better not to login using the same id  from both frontend and backend  .

Comment: I havebeen trying all these from yesterday onwards... I think the uninstallation of aphauserpoints plugin is causing all the problem.. but its not needed too...

Comment: thanks sapan for ur valuable reply...i hav got the solution 2,3 plugins of alphauserpoints need to be disabled still after uninstallation... now its working properly...